# MySQL subquery in select clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT op.*,
(op.total + op.total * 0.21) as price,
(SELECT p.`image` FROM oc_product` p WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id LIMIT 1) AS image
FROM `oc_order_product` op WHERE op.order_id = '80'
```

I can't found what is wrong with my query it's returning.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'oc_order_product`op WHERE op.order_id = '80'` LIMIT 0, 25' at
>   line 3

Comment: You miss a backtick before `oc_product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a back tick before `oc_product`, so

```
SELECT p.`image` FROM oc_product`
```

should look like

```
SELECT p.`image` FROM `oc_product`
```